# Ошибка компиляции ядра Android 3.4.113

Tags: android, linux, kernel

Собираю ядро 3.4.113 для MT6572, просто есть старье на интерпритаторе dalvik, которому лет наверное больше чем мне, вот пропатчил исходники c 3.4.67 до 3.4.113
Собираю:
Ошибка -Werror-implicit-function-declaration в monitor_hang.c
Выпилил ее из makefile, костыль жесткий, но сборка зато пошла дальше.
Теперь ошибка сборки wd_common_drv.c - undefined reference to `printk_sched'
В makefile ее упоминания нету.
Что делать?

Comment: Это не название файла, а функции. Вы когда обновляли ядро, читали про или смотрели на изменённый API?

Comment: Забавно, выпиливаем из исходного кода, а претензии к сборочной среде, или я что-то не понял, но у меня нет функции - догадаться!